# Queries with linq not returned what i want

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

i used linq in asp.net

i tried to return all students there they has 4 deals that the date of the deals between 01/04 to 11/04

this is the variables:

```
DealsFrom: "04/01/2018"
DealsMax: "4"
DealsMin: "4"
DealsTo: "04/11/2018"
```

this is the part of the linq code:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.DealsFrom))
{
    var fromDate = DateTime.Parse(filter.DealsFrom);
    students = students.Where(s => s.StudentDeals.Any(d => d.UsedDateTime >= fromDate));
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.DealsTo))
{
    var toDate = DateTime.Parse(filter.DealsTo);
    students = students.Where(s => s.StudentDeals.Any(d => d.UsedDateTime <= toDate));
}

if (filter.DealsMin.HasValue)
{
    students = students.Where(s => s.StudentDeals.Count >= filter.DealsMin);
}

if (filter.DealsMax.HasValue)
{
    students = students.Where(s => s.StudentDeals.Count <= filter.DealsMax);
}
```

but for now its return:
students the they have 4 deals with one or more deals between the dates.
I want that all the 4 deals will be between the dates.

what I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i want that all the 4 deals will be between the dates

Well, isn't it as easy as using `All` instead of `Any`?!

```
students = students.Where(s => s.StudentDeals.All(d => d.UsedDateTime >= fromDate));
// others too
```

Comment: No good, now when the input without dealsmin and dealsmax and only the dates its show all the students without to check if there is a deals between the dates

Answer (score 0):

as Tim described, you need All instead of any. Moreover it seems like there is issue with your conditions. Your statement is confusing though but if i am getting it right than i guess u need something that u need students who have max 4 deals within your dates. If this is your desired result than add conditions like

```
s.StudentDeals.All(d => d.UsedDateTime >= fromDate && d.UsedDateTime <= toDate && // so on)
```